# Should I sacrifice my innodb_buffer_pool _size/RAM to make space for query_cache_size?

Tags: mysql, innodb, query-performance, performance, query-cache

I have a 16GB dedicated Mysql server database. My innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to around 11GB. I am thinking of implementing the query cache in my system, which has a current size of 80MB. From where should I make this space, innodb_buffer_pool_size or RAM ?